# I am not sure whats wrong with this coding?

Tags: java

Below is my implementation for bubble sort.

It doesn't gives me any error. But still I am not getting the expected output?

```
package working_5_hours_coding_feels_good;

public class Working_5_hours_coding_feels_good {

    private static final int N = 3;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,j,temp ;
        int []A=new int[N];
        A[0]=12;
        A[1]=53;
        A[2]=2;
        System.out.println("this is in real form No sorting");
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
        System.out.print(A[i]+"  ");
        }
          for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
              for(i=0;i<N;i++)
                {
                      if (A[i]>A[i+1])
                        {
                         temp=A[i];
                          A[i]=A[i+1];
                          A[i+1]=temp;
                          }

                }

            }
        System.out.println("this is in bubble sorting procedure");
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
        System.out.println(A[i]+"  ");
        }  
    }

}
```

Comment: `it don't work` you have any better explanation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You are having a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
In this part of code, you have this loop :

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[i + 1];
                A[i + 1] = temp;
            }
 }
```

You are iterating until N, and trying to reach the line after the N+1 line (A[i+1]), which causes the error.

If you iterate this way, you won't have your error anymore :

```
for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: thank you very much I wish i had 15 rep to up vote the answer

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could have helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the inner for loop - 
You are now using limit till N and using index of array as [i+1] so at one point of time you hit N+1 which throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Change that condition to ->

```
for (i=0; i<N-1;i++) {
            if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) {
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[i + 1];
                A[i + 1] = temp;
            }
 }
```

Now it should hopefully work.